# Post to facebook wall offline access

Tags: php, facebook

I wanna build a system to push notifications on the users wall when the person is online or not on Facebook.

I will use some kind of "Login button" with offline_access and publish_actions.

But how can i know the user and push to the persons wall when the person is offline?

Answer (score 1):

See this documentation , I think it will help : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app_notifications/

And view this post : [Get long live access token from Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467272/get-long-live-access-token-from-facebook)