# Facebook - post on wall by cron

Tags: facebook, cron, facebook-wall

Can i post on wall by CRON when my account haven't permissions to my app?
This is my APP, i can manage her in https://developers.facebook.com/app and i'm admin of this APP. I want post from admin account, no from other users.

I use long-live access token but, when my account haven't permission to app API show error and API need this permissions.
Maybe offline_access? What about setAccessToken?

I user facebook PHP API.

Answer (score 0):

offline_access have been deprecated since SDK 3, so you should get a long-lived access token. [Get long live access token from Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467272/get-long-live-access-token-from-facebook)