# Facebook long lived Page Access Token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

I am administrator of facebook page which DOES NOT have a classic facebook account assigned. So I am not able to create any facebook application as you can see in Picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umeyL.png). How can I obtain long lived (never expiring) page access token, which I need to use Graph API? I need to post messages to the facebook page from my server.

Thanks for advice

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467272/get-long-live-access-token-from-facebook

Comment: as I said above, I can not create facebook application so I can not fill API Secret!

Comment: access right are linked to account, so is there any reason to not create an account that haves right to access to this page?

Answer (score 1):

You do need a User account that is admin of the Facebook Page in order to get a Page Token. Without a User account, it is not possible.

Here´s what you need to do:

- Authorize the User account in the App - which means, get a User Access Token
- Extend the User Token
- Get an Extended Page Token with `/me/accounts` or `/[page-id]?fields=access_token`

Some Links for more information:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

Comment: I am logged as a admin of the facebook page, I can get page token, but this token is only for 1 hour. So it is possible without user account, but I can not create facebook app without facebook user account. So there is no other way how to extend short lived page token?

Comment: not that i know, you get an extended page token with an extended user token only.

Comment: ok then, so I attached my test user account to facebook page and then I generated never expiring access token (using facebook app created by test user account) and now it is working and OK..thx for advice