# Swift Facebook graph fan page public photos

Tags: xcode, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get infos from a public page, but can't get anything, it says always that I need an access token.
How can I retrieve public info without asking the user to login to Facebook?

```
var request = "1537823733106575?fields=about"
    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: request, parameters: nil)
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
            println("Error: \(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            //println(result)
        }
    })
```

Here's an example code, I'm using Facebook SDK 4.01 and Swift.

Comment: Wondering why my question has been downvoted..?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a short lived access token https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ then turn that into a long lived access token using [Get long live access token from Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467272/get-long-live-access-token-from-facebook). This access token will be associated with your user id.