# Omniauth-Facebook: How to get Long-Lived Access Tokens?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

I followed the great [Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication?view=asciicast) to help me setup ominauth-facebook, but in his tutorial he only shows how to set it up with short-lived access tokens (hour or 2). How can we revise his tutorial to set it up with a long-lived access token (60 days)?

I've been reading over the [Facebook docs about it](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending) and this older [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467272/get-long-live-access-token-from-facebook).

Both links suggest adding some code like this (although the code varies slightly for each):

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

Where would one add this to?

From what I read it seems like they are making this awfully more complicated than it should be. Can someone put this in beginner friendly language?

### Let's get Personal.

My code varies slightly from Mr. Bates.

**initializers/ominauth.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, "1540352575225959", "ee957abf5e851c98574cdfaebb1355f4", {:scope => 'user_about_me'}
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#facebook'
```

**sessions_controller**

```
  def facebook
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tagger
  acts_as_taggable
  has_many :notifications
  has_many :activities
  has_many :liked_comments, through: :comment_likes, class_name: 'Comment', source: :liked_comment
  has_many :valuation_likes
  has_many :habit_likes
  has_many :goal_likes
  has_many :stat_likes
  has_many :comment_likes
  has_many :authentications
  has_many :habits, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :levels
  has_many :valuations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments
  has_many :goals, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :stats, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :results, through: :stats
  has_many :notes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :habits, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :notes, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :stats, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :results, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                  foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                  dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships,  source: :followed
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  before_save   :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, format: { with: /\A[a-z\sA-Z]+\z/,
    message: "only allows letters" }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, unless: -> { from_omniauth? }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

  def name
     read_attribute(:name).try(:titleize)
  end

  def count_mastered
    @res = habits.reduce(0) do |count, habit|
    habit.current_level == 6 ? count + 1 : count
    end
  end

  def count_challenged
    @challenged_count = habits.count - @res
  end

    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
      where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.image = auth.info.image
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.name = auth.info.name
        user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
        user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
        user.password = (0...8).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join
        user.email = (0...8).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join+"@mailinator.com"
        user.save!
      end
    end

  def self.koala(auth)
    access_token = auth['token']
    facebook = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
    facebook.get_object("me?fields=name,picture")
  end


  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Forgets a user. NOT SURE IF I REMOVE
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end

  # Activates an account.
  def activate
    update_attribute(:activated,    true)
    update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends activation email.
  def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
  end

  def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:reset_digest,  User.digest(reset_token))
    update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends password reset email.
  def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
  end

   # Returns true if a password reset has expired.
  def password_reset_expired?
    reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
  end

  def good_results_count
    results.good_count
  end

  # Follows a user.
  def follow(other_user)
    active_relationships.create(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

  # Unfollows a user.
  def unfollow(other_user)
    active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy
  end

  # Returns true if the current user is following the other user.
  def following?(other_user)
    following.include?(other_user)
  end

private 

    def from_omniauth? 
      provider && uid 
    end

      # Converts email to all lower-case.
    def downcase_email 
      self.email = email.downcase unless from_omniauth? 
    end

    # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
    def create_activation_digest
      self.activation_token  = User.new_token
      self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
    end
end
```

**facebook.js.coffee.erb**

```
jQuery ->
  $('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root"></div>')

  $.ajax
    url: "#{window.location.protocol}//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"
    dataType: 'script'
    cache: true


window.fbAsyncInit = ->
  FB.init(appId: '<%= 1540372976229929 %>', cookie: true)

  $('#sign_in').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    FB.login (response) ->
      window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback' if response.authResponse

  if $('#sign_out').length > 0
    FB.getLoginStatus (response) ->
      window.location = $('#sign_out').attr("href") if !response.authResponse
```

**Source:** [omniauth-facebook](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook).

"Being a good programmer is 3% talent and 97% not being distracted by the internet."

Comment: Since you're well on your way to resolve the issue, I won't interfere... but I did have a similar challenge as I was building an OAuth2 library for the Plezi framework. You can have a look at [the code for the final authorization token](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi/blob/d13fcc0422681a09605ac1b5abda8d3a7f15ce19/lib/plezi/oauth/auth_controller.rb#L140-L154). It get's you a token that lasts of about 30 days. The token needs to be renewed periodically. The code is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks unless you change the SSL verify mode for the OAuth HTTPS request.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue like you did before with the app that I am currently building. The solution I found suggests using Koala authentication to prolong the initial short-lived token immediately after its creation.

The adaptation of solution that worked well for me is as follows...

First, include `gem 'koala', '2.0.0'` in your Gemfile. Also, visit [Koala github site](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) for more info.

Now let's apply the above to **user.rb**'s `from_omniauth` method...

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
   # Sets 60 day auth token
   oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new("1540352575225959", "ee957abf5e851c98574cdfaebb1355f4")
   new_access_info = oauth.exchange_access_token_info auth.credentials.token

   new_access_token = new_access_info["access_token"]
   new_access_expires_at = DateTime.now + new_access_info["expires"].to_i.seconds

  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.image = auth.info.image
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.name = auth.info.name
    user.oauth_token = new_access_token # auth.credentials.token <- your old token. Not needed anymore.
    user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
    user.password = (0...8).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join
    user.email = (0...8).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join+"@mailinator.com"
    user.save!
  end
end
```

### **Additional info:**

I have also noticed that you are generating some dummy values for User's email and password. May I suggest you rather use SecureRandom library for doing so. Whilst the possibility that your code is very unlikely to result in a collision of values, at least for the email I suggest changing `(0...8).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join+"@mailinator.com"` to a more stable `SecureRandom.hex + "@mailinator.com"`. This is especially important if you are using emails as the way to log users in the application.

I hope this resolves your issue. All best, Tim.

## **UPDATE:**

I am glad that we managed to answer your question and solve all your other issues together, however here is an update in regards to **refactoring** of code I was talking about earlier...

Consider a situation, whereby a user, that logged in through Facebook, changes some data about themselves on your website. Let's say they change their name, email or an avatar. This will work fine **until** the same user tries to log back in again. What will happen is that **from_omniauth** method will get triggered again and override those changes. This is bad and the way to prevent this is by doing the following...

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  .
  .
  .
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.image = auth.info.image unless user.image != nil
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.name = auth.info.name unless user.name != nil
    user.oauth_token = new_access_token 
    user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
    user.password = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64 unless user.password != nil
    user.email = SecureRandom.hex + "@mailinator.com" unless user.email != nil
    user.activated = true
    user.save!
  end
```

The key is the use of `unless user.image != nil` which ensures that your image is only going to be set if the initial value of `:image` is `nil`. If say the user changes the image, the value won't be `nil` and from_omniauth won't change it. The same goes for name, email and password. Don't set it to anything else.

Also, note that I used `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64` instead of your `(0...8).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join`. This is because `urlsafe_base64` generates a random URL-safe base64 string, like `i0XQ-7gglIsHGV2_BNPrdQ==` which is perfect for a dummy password and looks elegant too.

On the other hand, the reason I used `hex` for emails is because it creates a random hexadecimal string, like `eb693ec8252cd630102fd0d0fb7c3485`, which will not upset your validations, if you happen to have some regex to validate emails (which ideally you should).

Comment: You can also use `new_access_token = oauth.get_app_access_token(auth.credentials.token)` directly. Just a helper method to extract the token from the info hash

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `exchange_access_token_info` method from your instance of `Koala::Facebook::OAuth`