# How to get facebook page likes using long live access token

Tags: php, facebook

I am getting facebook page likes count using following link

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{page_name}?access_token={access_token}
```

it's working fine but the access token will expires every 2 hours, and i create the long live `access_token`,when by the replace of `access_token` with long live access token, i didn't get like count.

Comment: should work... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467272/get-long-live-access-token-from-facebook

Comment: why not use an app token instead? what token are you using right now? user or page token?

Comment: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/